# REST Annotated classes not part of org.superbiz package are not being deployed by TomEE Plume 7.0.4

Tags: apache-tomee, tomee-7

On TomEE Plume 7.0.3/4 when I change my REST annotated classes package from `org.superbiz` then they are no more deployed when I deploy the war file.

Sample class is given below

```
package com.abc.rest.application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/rest-prefix")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(SimpleRESTPojo.class, SimpleRESTEJB.class));
    }
}
```

Now `ApplicationConfig` class is never read by the TomEE Plume. What configuration I need to make so that TomEE recognize my rest application config class and other jax-rs, ejb and jpa annotated classes.

Comment: Again, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: It seems my package names has to start with org. to use JPA & EJB. Is it a real necessity.

Answer (score 0):

In system.properties set openejb.classloader.forced-load=com.abc
then only my application packages would be loaded. Tricky to understand.